# Most specific method with matches of both fixed/variable arity (varargs)

Tags: java, variadic-functions, jls

In [section 15.12.2.5 of the Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#301183), it talks about how to choose the most specific method in both cases of methods with fixed arity and methods of variable arity (i.e. **`varargs`**).

What I  can't find in the JLS is anything about deciding between two methods where *one is of fixed arity and one of variable arity* however. For example:

```
public interface SomeApi {
    public String getSomething(String arg);       // method 1
    public String getSomething(String ... args);  // method 2
}
```

Compiles just fine as one would expect (*for reasons outlined by Yoni below*). This calling code compiles also:

```
SomeApi api = ...
Object o = api.getSomething("Hello");
```

and if you run it, `method #1` (i.e. the non-varargs method) is called. Why is this calling-code not ambiguous? Why is the fixed arity method more specific than the variable-arity one? Can someone point me to the relevant bit of the spec?

Comment: just curious... did you have a specific reason for understanding besides an academic interest? (I'm trying to implement runtime dispatch selection + wondered who else might be doing the same)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first method resolution phase considers only fixed arity methods and the process is terminated if a match is found, before any varargs methods are considered.

From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se6/html/expressions.html#15.12.2.2

> 15.12.2.2 Phase 1: Identify **Matching Arity** Methods Applicable by
>   Subtyping
>
> If no method applicable by subtyping
>   is found, the search for applicable
>   methods continues with phase 2
>   (§15.12.2.3). *Otherwise, the most
>   specific method (§15.12.2.5) is chosen
>   among the methods that are applicable
>   by subtyping.*

(My emphasis.)

Comment: Thanks Alex - I was not seeing the wood for the trees. Damn those trees!

Answer (score -1):

I can't point you to the spec, but logically,

```
getSomething(String...args)
```

translates to

```
getSomething(String[] args)
```

with no ambiguity

Comment: Yes - I understand that. I was asking why the calling code is not ambiguous - I've clarified my intent in the question