# a code can run in eclipse, but not javac

Tags: java, eclipse, list, collections, type-safety

for code

```
import java.util.*;

interface Sample{

}

public class TypeTest implements Sample{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<Object> objs = new HashSet<>();
        objs.add(new TypeTest());
        List<? extends Sample> objList = (List<? extends Sample>) new ArrayList<>(objs);
        for (Sample t : objList) {
            System.out.println(t.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

it can run in eclipse and output `TypeTest@7852e922` but `javac` will get an error:

```
incompatible types: ArrayList<Object> cannot be converted to List<? extends Sample>
```

Comment: Do you have 2 different JDKs installed on your system?

Comment: What version of javac? What Java level is your Eclipse project configured to use?

Comment: By the way, I don't think you even need the cast if you use a recent version of Java (7+); the compiler can imply the type parameters of the instantiation from the variable declaration.

Comment: Im able to reproduce this with jdk 1.8 and Eclipse 4.5 using the same jdk. The problem seems to be similar to...http://stackoverflow.com/q/2858799/1069114 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/3000177/1069114.

Comment: Yes eclipse allowing this, is wrong. Though honestly: diamond operator plus cast _is_ perverse.

Comment: @Blue no, only install JDK1.8.0_92

Comment: @E-Riz javac version is 1.8.0_92 and java level also configured as 1.8 in eclipse project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code *should not* compile.  The problem is that the inferred type of `new ArrayList<>(objs)` is `ArrayList<Object>` because you have passed the constructor a `Set<Object>` as the parameter.  But `ArrayList<Object>` is not a subtype of `List<? extends Sample>`.

Change

```
    Set<Object> objs = new HashSet<>();
```

to

```
    Set<? extends Sample> objs = new HashSet<>();
```

and the code should compile ... provided that TypeTest is a subtype of `Sample`.

Comment: I agree with you, but eclipse allow this. is there any reason for eclipse to do this?

Comment: 'Cos the Eclipse compiler is buggy?