# Can I pass an array as arguments to a method with variable arguments in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, backwards-compatibility, variadic-functions

I'd like to be able to create a function like:

```
class A {
  private String extraVar;
  public String myFormat(String format, Object ... args){
    return String.format(format, extraVar, args);
  }
}
```

The problem here is that `args` is treated as `Object[]` in the method `myFormat`, and thus is a single argument to `String.format`, while I'd like every single `Object` in `args` to be passed as a new argument. Since `String.format` is also a method with variable arguments, this should be possible.

If this is not possible, is there a method like `String.format(String format, Object[] args)`? In that case I could prepend `extraVar` to `args` using a new array and pass it to that method.

Comment: I can't help but wonder why this question is a "is this valid" kind of question. Couldn't you have just tried it? Don't overdo asking, you'll do yourself more harm than good.

Comment: true enough, this could have been easily tested. however, the nice thing about a question like this is that it exposes the topic and solicits interesting answers.

Comment: I actually tried the code above, with the intention to pass the array args as arguments to the method. However, I didn't realize that I should've prepended extraVar to args first. When you know that variable arguments are treated as an array (even outside the method), this is of course quite logical.

Answer (score 209, accepted):

The underlying type of a [variadic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic) method `function(Object... args)` *is* `function(Object[] args)`. Sun added varargs in this manner to preserve backwards compatibility.

So you should just be able to prepend `extraVar` to `args` and call `String.format(format, args)`.

Comment: Passing an argument of type `X[]` into a method `x(X... xs)` gives the following warning in Eclipse: `Type X[] of the last argument to method x(X...) doesn't exactly match the vararg parameter type. Cast to X[] to confirm the non-varargs invocation, or pass individual arguments of type X for a varargs invocation.`

Answer (score 388):

Yes, a `T...` is only a syntactic sugar for a `T[]`.

#### [JLS 8.4.1 Format parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.1)

> The last formal parameter in a list is special; it may be a *variable arity* parameter, indicated by an elipsis following the type.
>
> If the last formal parameter is a variable arity parameter of type `T`, it is considered to define a formal parameter of type `T[]`. The method is then a *variable arity* method. Otherwise, it is a *fixed arity* method. Invocations of a variable arity method may contain more actual argument expressions than formal parameters. All the actual argument expressions that do not correspond to the formal parameters preceding the variable arity parameter will be evaluated and the results stored into an array that will be passed to the method invocation.

Here's an example to illustrate:

```
public static String ezFormat(Object... args) {
    String format = new String(new char[args.length])
        .replace("\0", "[ %s ]");
    return String.format(format, args);
}
public static void main(String... args) {
    System.out.println(ezFormat("A", "B", "C"));
    // prints "[ A ][ B ][ C ]"
}
```

And yes, the above `main` method is valid, because again, `String...` is just `String[]`. Also, because arrays are covariant, a `String[]` is an `Object[]`, so you can also call `ezFormat(args)` either way.

#### See also

- [Java language guide/varargs](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html)

---

#### Varargs gotchas #1: passing `null`

How varargs are resolved is quite complicated, and sometimes it does things that may surprise you.

Consider this example:

```
static void count(Object... objs) {
    System.out.println(objs.length);
}

count(null, null, null); // prints "3"
count(null, null); // prints "2"
count(null); // throws java.lang.NullPointerException!!!
```

Due to how varargs are resolved, the last statement invokes with `objs = null`, which of course would cause `NullPointerException` with `objs.length`. If you want to give one `null` argument to a varargs parameter, you can do either of the following:

```
count(new Object[] { null }); // prints "1"
count((Object) null); // prints "1"
```

#### Related questions

The following is a sample of some of the questions people have asked when dealing with varargs:

- [bug with varargs and overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521293/bug-with-varargs-and-overloading)
- [How to work with varargs and reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600854/how-to-work-with-varargs-and-reflection)
- [Most specific method with matches of both fixed/variable arity (varargs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321657/most-specific-method-with-matches-of-both-fixed-variable-arity-varargs)

---

#### Vararg gotchas #2: adding extra arguments

As you've found out, the following doesn't "work":

```
    String[] myArgs = { "A", "B", "C" };
    System.out.println(ezFormat(myArgs, "Z"));
    // prints "[ [Ljava.lang.String;@13c5982 ][ Z ]"
```

Because of the way varargs work, `ezFormat` actually gets 2 arguments, the first being a `String[]`, the second being a `String`. If you're passing an array to varargs, and you want its elements to be recognized as individual arguments, and you also need to add an extra argument, then you have no choice but to create *another array* that accommodates the extra element.

Here are some useful helper methods:

```
static <T> T[] append(T[] arr, T lastElement) {
    final int N = arr.length;
    arr = java.util.Arrays.copyOf(arr, N+1);
    arr[N] = lastElement;
    return arr;
}
static <T> T[] prepend(T[] arr, T firstElement) {
    final int N = arr.length;
    arr = java.util.Arrays.copyOf(arr, N+1);
    System.arraycopy(arr, 0, arr, 1, N);
    arr[0] = firstElement;
    return arr;
}
```

Now you can do the following:

```
    String[] myArgs = { "A", "B", "C" };
    System.out.println(ezFormat(append(myArgs, "Z")));
    // prints "[ A ][ B ][ C ][ Z ]"

    System.out.println(ezFormat(prepend(myArgs, "Z")));
    // prints "[ Z ][ A ][ B ][ C ]"
```

---

#### Varargs gotchas #3: passing an array of primitives

It doesn't "work":

```
    int[] myNumbers = { 1, 2, 3 };
    System.out.println(ezFormat(myNumbers));
    // prints "[ [I@13c5982 ]"
```

Varargs only works with reference types. Autoboxing does not apply to array of primitives. The following works:

```
    Integer[] myNumbers = { 1, 2, 3 };
    System.out.println(ezFormat(myNumbers));
    // prints "[ 1 ][ 2 ][ 3 ]"
```

Comment: Using Object... variadic parameters makes it difficult to use additional signatures as the compiler identifies ambiguity between the signatures where even a primitive argument can be autoboxed to Object.

Comment: There is a missing gotcha : if your method has a last param of type Object... and you call it passing a String[] for instance. The compiler doesn't know if your array is the first item of the varargs or is the equivalent of all the varargs. It will warn you.

Comment: Passing an argument of type `X[]` into a method `x(X... xs)` gives the following warning in Eclipse: `Type X[] of the last argument to method x(X...) doesn't exactly match the vararg parameter type. Cast to X[] to confirm the non-varargs invocation, or pass individual arguments of type X for a varargs invocation.`

Comment: returning X[] to a method that that takes(X ... xs) ... i doubt it will be expanded.

Comment: Is there a convenience method in StringUtils that can handle gotcha #2, without having to add all the elements to a single input array argument?  For instance: StringUtils.format(formatString, argArray, extraElement)

Comment: I suggests replacing `new String(new char[args.length]) .replace("\0", "[ %s ]")` with `"[ %s ]".repeat(args.length)` which works since Java 11, as the work-around is distracting from the actual point of the example.

Answer (score 30):

It's ok to pass an array - in fact it amounts to the same thing

```
String.format("%s %s", "hello", "world!");
```

is the same as

```
String.format("%s %s", new Object[] { "hello", "world!"});
```

It's just syntactic sugar - the compiler converts the first one into the second, since the underlying method is expecting an array for the [vararg](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) parameter.

See

- [Varargs - J2SE 1.5 Documentation](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html)

Answer (score 7):

jasonmp85 is right about passing a different array to `String.format`. The size of an array can't be changed once constructed, so you'd have to pass a new array instead of modifying the existing one.

```
Object newArgs = new Object[args.length+1];
System.arraycopy(args, 0, newArgs, 1, args.length);
newArgs[0] = extraVar; 
String.format(format, extraVar, args);
```

Answer (score 5):

I was having same issue.

```
String[] arr= new String[] { "A", "B", "C" };
Object obj = arr;
```

And then passed the obj as varargs argument.
It worked.

Comment: Please add that too.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to #2 of @genelubricant - in case read-only is enough and if you want to swap a little extra effort for gaining some of the conveniences of a `List` - copying the array is not necessarily required and wrapping it, plus injecting the desired extra value at an arbitrary index at access time, can be achieved like this:

```
public static <T> List<Object> wrappedUnmodfiableListInsertion(final T insert, final Integer insertIdx, final T... source) {
  final boolean isInsertion = insertIdx != null;
  return new AbstractList<Object>() {
    @Override
    public int size() {
      return source != null ? isInsertion ? source.length + 1 : source.length : 0;
    }
    @Override
    public Object get(int index) {
      if (source == null) {
        if (isInsertion) {
          return index == insertIdx && index == 0 ? insert : null;
        }
        return EMPTY_LIST;
      } 
      if (isInsertion) {
        if (index == insertIdx) {
          return insert;
        } 
        return source[insertIdx > index ? index : index - 1];
      }
      return source[index];
    }
  };
}
```