# Pass arguments to "new" operator through an array in ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3

How can I achieve the following for any number of elements in the `arg` array? If it was a function, I'd [use Function.apply()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260875/pass-arguments-from-an-array-to-an-actionscript-method-with-rest-argument), but I can't figure out how to do it with the `new` operator.

```
var arg:Array = [1,2];
new MyClass( arg[0], arg[1] );
```

Comment: What are you trying achieve? Why not just pass the array as a separate argument?

Comment: @Ancide: I've got an array and want to instantiate a class with those elements as arguments, without compromising type safety and compiler checks in other parts of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set up your class to accept a list of arguments using `... args` you can pass in as many as you like.  Then in the constructor you will access them just like a normal array.

```
class MyClass 
{
    public function MyClass(... args):void
    {
        //args is an Array containing all the properties sent to the constructor
        trace(args.length);
    }
}
```

Comment: I wish I could merge your answer and Jim's. And add a better explanation to how this will be invoked so there will not be a misunderstanding that passing one array will separate it into separate args.

Comment: Yes. Andy, if you intend to only ever pass the full array, go with Jim's answer. If you intend to only pass some elements, or elements from different arrays that should be combined into a single array in `MyClass`, use my answer.

Comment: Then I'd need to edit the class constructor, which is being used in other places. I wouldn't want to compromise AS3's type security in those places because of this need. Also, I'd like a solution that works with classes that I can'd modify.

Comment: The constructor is mostly called "properly", but I'd also, on one point in the code, like to call it in a Function.apply()-like manner. It would not really be suitable to change the class constructor.

Comment: Undeclared overloading of a constructor is not permitted in AS3, so it will be necessary to modify the constructor of MyClass one way or another if you insist on passing this though the constructor.

Comment: @shane: Just like the [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260875/pass-arguments-from-an-array-to-an-actionscript-method-with-rest-argument) didn't require overloading, I suspect that there's a way to call the constructor indirectly.

Comment: I wish I could vote this question up more than once, and that I had more time to research it, but maybe this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3874869/can-i-use-apply-with-constructor-to-pass-arbitrary-number-of-parameters/3936708#3936708

Answer (score 1):

Dont pass each element of the array, just pass the array.

```
var arg:Array = [1,2];
new MyClass(arg);
```

Then inside of your class, loop through the array.

Comment: Then I'd need to edit the class constructor, which is being used in other places. I wouldn't want to compromise AS3's type security in those places because of this need. Also, I'd like a solution that works with classes that I can'd modify.

Comment: You can overload the class constructor. You can make one that accepts an array, and one that excepts an explicit list of values.

This way, you can implement this without breaking previous invocations of this constructor.

Comment: You can't overload any functions in ActionScript 3.0

Answer (score 1):

It is unfortunately not possible, because there is no way to directly access the constructor method of a Class object.

Note: If you'd be using a Function object to make up your class (prototype inheritance), then it would be possible, but i figure, this is not an option for you.

You could work around the problem with a little (ugly) helper method, on which you can read about here: http://jacksondunstan.com/articles/398

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments is is not possible to apply settings on the constructor, but you could use this trick to set properties on a new instance of a class (which should be public)

```
public function setProps(o:Object, props:Object):* {
 for (var n:String in props) {
   o[n] = props[n];
 }
 return o;
}
```

.. use it like this

```
var args:Object = {x:1, y:2};
var instance:MyClass = setProps( new MyClass(), args ) );
```

**source:**
http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2010/05/quick_way_to_se.html