# Understanding unexpected behaviors of varargs in Java

Tags: java

I was reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5405740/6357916) answer, where it says

> Note also that calling a generic vararg method with an explicit array parameter may silently produce different behaviour than expected:
>
> ```
> public <T> void foo(T... params) { ... }
> int[] arr = {1, 2, 3};
> foo(arr); // passes an int[][] array containing a single int[] element
> ```

Similar behavior is exaplained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2926653/6357916) answer gotcha 3:

> ```
> int[] myNumbers = { 1, 2, 3 };
> System.out.println(ezFormat(myNumbers));
> // prints "[ [I@13c5982 ]"
> ```
>
> Varargs only works with reference types. Autoboxing does not apply to array of primitives. The following works:
>
> ```
> Integer[] myNumbers = { 1, 2, 3 };
> System.out.println(ezFormat(myNumbers));
> // prints "[ 1 ][ 2 ][ 3 ]"
> ```

I tried simpler examples:

```
private static <T> void tVarargs(T ... s)
{
    System.out.println("\n\ntVarargs ==========");
    System.out.println(s.getClass().getName());
    System.out.println(s.length);
    for(T i : s)
        System.out.print(s + ",");
}

private static void objVarargs(Object ... a)
{
    System.out.println("\n\nobjVarargs =========== ");
    System.out.println(a.getClass().getName());
    System.out.println(a.length);
    for(Object i : a)
        System.out.print(i + ",");
}

int[] intarr = {1,2,3}; 
Integer[] Intarr = {1,2,3};

objVarargs(intarr);
objVarargs(Intarr);

tVarargs(intarr);
tVarargs(Intarr);
```

This prints

```
objVarargs =========== 
[Ljava.lang.Object;
1
[I@7852e922,

objVarargs =========== 
[Ljava.lang.Integer;
3
1,2,3,

tVarargs ==========
[[I
1
[[I@4e25154f,

tVarargs ==========
[Ljava.lang.Integer;
3
[Ljava.lang.Integer;@70dea4e,[Ljava.lang.Integer;@70dea4e,[Ljava.lang.Integer;@70dea4e,
```

- Notice passing `intarr` to `tVarargs` results in creation of single *2 dimensional array* `[[I` wit *single element*. However, what is the types of this array?
- Also, passing `intarr`  to `objVarargs()` results in creation of *1-D array* `[Ljava.lang.Object` containing *single array element*.
- For rest, it creates 1-D array with as many elements as passed - the desired behavior.

Can someone shed more light on first two behaviors? Are these two different behaviors or same behaviors, I mean having different or same reason behind them. What are those reasons, in depth? Is there any other cases resulting in different unexpected behavior?

Comment: I am not sure what is confusing you here. `Type...` is just `Type[]` but allows us to pass arguments of `Type` as list instead of wrapping it into array manually. `<T>` is limited to reference types only (it can't represent primitive type like `int`) which means `T...` as `T[]` can't be `int[]`. If you pass `int[]` array then most specific object type which `T` can use is array itself. So since `T` is now `int[]` `T...` is like `int[]...` which results in `int[][]` (that is what `[[I` represents). `Object...` is simply `Object[]` array and that is what you see in other method

Answer (score 5):

These two behaviors result from the same issue - both generic type parameters and `Object` variables can only hold reference types. A primitive (such as `int`) is not a reference type, so passing an `int` array to a varargs method (and it doesn't matter if it's `Object ... a` or `T ... s`) results in the method accepting an array having a single element, and that single element is the `int` array.

Therefore you can consider it as a 2 dimensional `int` array (i.e. `int[][]`) containing a single row.

Note that you have a typo in `tVarargs(T ... s)` which results in confusing output. It should be `System.out.print(i + ",");`, not `System.out.print(s + ",");`

Once you fix that, both methods produce the same output for the `Integer[]` input:

```
[Ljava.lang.Integer;
3
1,2,3,
```

The difference in the outputs for the `int[]` input results from the fact that in `objVarargs(Object ... a)`, the type of the varargs array is `Object[]`, and in `tVarargs(T ... s)` it's `T[]` (and when `T` is an `int[]`, the type of the array is an `int[][]`).

BTW, `[[I` is the class name of a two dimensional `int` array (i.e. `int[][]`).