# String.format() takes an array as a single argument

Tags: java, string, string-formatting

Why this does work OK?:

```
String f = "Mi name is %s %s.";
System.out.println(String.format(f, "John", "Connor"));
```

And this doesnt?:

```
String f = "Mi name is %s %s.";
System.out.println(String.format(f, (Object)new String[]{"John","Connor"}));
```

If the method String.format takes a vararg Object?

It compiles OK but when I execute this the String.format() takes the vararg Object as a single an unique argument (the toString() value of the array itself), so it throws a MissingFormatArgumentException because it cannot match with the second string specifier (%s).

How can I make it work?
Thanks in advance, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: not sure but can you check without casting string array to object?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that after the cast to `Object`, the compiler doesn't know that you're passing an array. Try casting the second argument to `(Object[])` instead of `(Object)`.

```
System.out.println(String.format(f, (Object[])new String[]{"John","Connor"}));
```

Or just don't use a cast at all:

```
System.out.println(String.format(f, new String[]{"John","Connor"}));
```

although that might generate a compiler warning. (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2925300/535871) for a little more info.)

The cleanest, I think, would be to avoid a `String[]` in the first place:

```
System.out.println(String.format(f, new Object[]{"John","Connor"}));
```

Comment: Thanks, it works with Object[] cast. The cast is necessary to avoid a compilation warning. Thanks again.

Comment: @Dragurne - To avoid the compiler warning and the cast, you could use `new Object[]{"John","Connor"}`.

Answer (score 21):

Use this : (I would recommend this way)

```
String f = "Mi name is %s %s.";
System.out.println(String.format(f, (Object[])new String[]{"John","Connor"}));
```

OR

```
String f = "Mi name is %s %s.";
System.out.println(String.format(f, new String[]{"John","Connor"}));
```

But if you use this way, you will get following warning :

> The argument of type `String[]` should explicitly be cast to `Object[]` for the invocation of the `varargs` method `format(String, Object...)` from type `String`. It could alternatively be cast to `Object` for a `varargs` invocation.