# Java array syntax alternative

Tags: java, arrays, syntax

I just saw someone use this alternate syntax for arrays and was wondering:

Is

```
public void fn(Character[]...){}
```

equivalent to

```
public void fn(Character[]){} //(i.e. "..." is redundant)
```

or is it equivalent to

```
public void fn(Character[][]){}
```

Comment: Did you see this as a function parameter? If so that means variable number of arguments.

Comment: Right. I think Asaph answered your question then

Comment: This post has a detailed answer to the underlying question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2926653/702638

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using varargs you will allow multiple parameters, using just a single 2D array you only allow one parameter. They might result in one 2D array, but they strongly differ in the way it's called.

Small sample:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        doSomething(new char[5], new char[6]);
        doSomething(new char[2][3]);
    }

    private static void doSomething(char[]... args){
        for(char[] s : args){
            System.out.println(s.length);
        }
    }
}
```

Works just fine:

```
5
6
3
3
```

However if you would just use `char[][]`, the first way of calling wouldn't work. That's the difference.

`char` vs `Char` makes no functional difference in this case, although you might want to keep the last remark from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2926653/1864167) in mind.