# Isn't function that accepts vararg Object... argument ambigous when called with Object[] param?

Tags: java, variadic-functions

So basically from my searches on StackOverflow, this popped out (correct me if wrong):

1. You can define function that accepts variable argument (in this case any Object) count this way:

   ```
   public void varadric(Object... arguments) {
       //I'm a dummy function
   }
   ```
2. You call this method with any count of arguments (which extend Object) and you'll get one argument being `Object[]` in the function:

   ```
    public static main() {
        varadric("STRING", new ArrayList<int>());
    }
    public void varadric(Object... arguments) {
        System.out.println("I've received "+arguments.length+" arguments of any Object subclass type.");
    }
   ```
3. You can instead somehow [generate the input as Object[] array and pass as a single parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2925153/607407) without any change:

   ```
   public static main() {
       Object[] args = new Object[2];
       args[0] = "STRING";
       args[1] = new ArrayList<int>());
       //Should say it got 2 arguments again!
       varadric(args);
   }
   ```

Now my question is: Since `Object[]` implements `Object` too, does it mean it's not possible to pass it in varargs (ending up with nested array?)?

Imagine following scenario with more specific description:

```
 public void varadric(Object[]... arguments) {
      //I'm a function that expects array of arrays
      // - but I'm not sure if I'll allways get that
 }
```

Could someone make this clear for me?

Comment: Try invoking `varadric((Object)args);` to  see the different behavior. In that case, it will be considered as a single argument and wrapped within its own `Object[]`. That is, the variable `arguments` within the `varadric` method will be an `Object[]` containing an `Object[]` containing a `String` and an `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there are a few options:

- Create an array yourself:

  ```
  varadric(new Object[] { array })
  ```
- Declare a local variable of type `Object` and get the compiler to wrap *that* in an array:

  ```
  Object tmp = array;
  varadric(tmp);
  ```
- A variation on the above - just cast:

  ```
  varadric((Object) array);
  ```

But yes, you're right to say that when presented with a single argument of type `Object[]` and a varargs parameter declared as `Object... foo`, the compiler *won't* wrap it because it in an array, because it doesn't need to.

Answer (score 1):

It will be a 2D array.
This declaration `public void varadric(Object[]... arguments)` will receive an array (`...`) of `Object[]`
Example:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object[] o = new Object[2]; 
        o[1] = "hi";
        t(o);
    }

    public static void t(Object[]... arg) {
        System.out.println(arg[0][1]);
    }
}
```

will print:
`hi`