# passing variables into a method

Tags: java, variables, arraylist

I have a process:

- get widths of column table
- refresh
- set widths of column table

Here are my methods

This gets the column width table

```
public ArrayList<Integer> getJTableColumnsWidth() {
  ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < tableR.getColumnModel().getColumnCount(); i++) 
    {
        TableColumn column = tableR.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
        System.out.print(column.getPreferredWidth());
        list.add(column.getPreferredWidth());

    }
 return list;    
}
```

There are 18 columns in my table.

I then want to pass each number of my arraylist into a method like below..

```
setTableWidths(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,x9,x10,x11,x12,x13,x14,x15,x16,x17,x18)
```

where each number is just each number in the arraylist and contains a width.

I can call each number of the arraylist by calling

```
getJTableColumnsWidth()
```

but then how is this passed directly to `setTableWidths(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5....)`?

Comment: You mean like `list = getJTableColumnsWidth();` then `setTableWidths(list.get(0), list.get(1), ...)`?

Comment: @ cricket_007 is there a more elegant way of doing this since if i had 100 columns this could get a little tedious..

Comment: I would just give the list itself as a parameter. You could then do a for-loop over the list within the method to set all the column widths

Answer (score 1):

You have an `ArrayList<Integer>`, and want to pass its contents as arguments to a method.

**If the method is defined to accept a fixed number of arguments**, then you can pass those arguments one-by-one.

```
setTableWidths( list.get(0), list.get(1), list.get(2) ... // etc.
```

Alternatively, you could define a `setTableWidths()` method that accepts a `List<Integer>` or array.

**If the method supports a variable number of arguments**, then you can convert the list into an array, and pass the array to the method:

```
setTableWidths( list.toArray( new Integer[0] ));
```

Comment: No, you can pass a single array containing all the arguments. If the method is declared `setTableWidths( Integer... args )`, then args is of type Integer[]. More detail on this capability is in the prior question: ["Can I pass an array as arguments to a method with variable arguments in Java?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925153/can-i-pass-an-array-as-arguments-to-a-method-with-variable-arguments-in-java)

Comment: I don't think OP has a method with variable arguments

Comment: @cricket_007 - Good point, that was unclear. I've covered both cases.

Comment: @Andy Thomas is there a more elegant way of doing this since if i had a table with 100 columns, this could be a bit painful...?

Comment: @MrAssistance - You could pass an array or a list. Or you could write a loop that gets and sets one width at a time. Or sometimes a UI framework will let you define a method that provides the width of an indexed column when requested>