# Why List<Integer[]> listOfArrays = Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{1, 2}) doesn't compile?

Tags: java, variadic-functions

1) OK

```
List<int[]> listOfArrays1 = Arrays.asList( new int[]{1, 2} );
```

2) OK

```
List<int[]> listOfArrays2 = Arrays.asList( new int[]{1, 2}, new int[]{3, 4} );
```

3) Compile error `Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<Integer> to List<Integer[]>`

```
List<Integer[]> listOfArrays3 = Arrays.asList( new Integer[]{1, 2} );
```

4) OK

```
List<Integer[]> listOfArrays4 = Arrays.asList( new Integer[]{1, 2},  new Integer[]{3, 4} );
```

This is the signature for `asList`: `public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a)`

`asList` expects 0 or more "a" of type T. My "a" is `new Integer[]{1, 2}` and it is of type `Integer[]`. So, why is it generating a `List<Integer>` instead of a `List<Integer[]>`?

Comment: Please explain how 1 and 2 didn't show any error. `List` doesn't work with primitive `int`.

Comment: @Sufian `int[]` is not primitive. It's an object.

Comment: (1) resolves correctly is because `T` can be `int[]` but not `int`. Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721546/why-dont-java-generics-support-primitive-types

Comment: OP, I suggest you read the answers in the chain of duplicate questions that have been marked here and determine if they are at all satisfactory (I don't think they are). If not, edit your question and at the top explain why you think this is not a duplicate. Maybe then the mark will be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at the problem example **(3rd)**:

```
List<Integer[]> listOfArrays3 = Arrays.asList( new Integer[]{1, 2} );
```

As you showed, the method signature is:

```
public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a)
```

In this particular case, the single `Integer[]` is being considered for the `T...`. An array or an unspecified number of the same object can be supplied to `T...`. Since you specified one array, the `T` is regarded as `Integer` (and `T...` becomes `Integer[]`).

When you supply an `int[]` as a single argument **(1st)**, the compiler doesn't automatically wrap this to an `Integer[]` because such an object is different from an `int[]`. Because `int` is not an object, the only object type that can fit `T` is `int[]` (which builds the parameter as an `int[][]`).

Supplying two `int[]`s **(2nd)** is much more obvious, as the compiler can only regard two arrays for `T...` as `int[]`s, thus `T...` is also `int[][]`.

When you supply two `Integer[]`s **(4th)**, it is more obvious again that the compiler has no choice but to regard the two parameters which make up `T...` as `Integer[]` (which becomes a single array: `Integer[][]`).

**Edit: Supplying an array as a vararg:**

You *can* supply a single array as a vararg. Let's take an example without a generic:

```
public int iLoveMeSomeInts(int...nums)
```

Supplying an `int[]` to this method as an argument does work. The array is regarded as a vararg of `int`s for the purposes of validating the signature, then the vararg is regarded as an `int[]` for the method's internal logic.

The difference in your example is that the argument is `T...`. A generic `T` **must** be an object, so the compiler cannot regard an `int[]` as a vararg of `int...` in this case. The compiler then has no choice but to regard the `int[]` as a single element in a vararg of `int[]...` (because `int[]` is an object). There is no ambiguity in this.

However, because `Integer` *is* an object, the compiler will use a single `Integer[]` as `Integer...`.

What's even cooler is this: if you wanted an `Integer[]` returned using the method in question, and still only supplied a single `Integer[]`, you could call:

```
Arrays.<Integer[]>asList(new Integer[] {1, 2});
```

This forces the compiler to regard your single `Integer[]` as `Integer[]...`.

Comment: I guess I didn't really know how varargs work.

Comment: varvargs are great, because you can supply any number of the same object, and in the method itself that argument is treated as an array. The gotcha here is that a generic `T` must be an object, so supplying an `int[]` will not count as a vararg of `int`s.

Comment: So in other words (if I understood this correctly), case 3 is ambiguous because it can be interpreted as both two arguments `(1, 2)` and one argument `(new Integer[]{1,2})`. It happens to be the case that the compiler decides to choose the first one and if you are expecting the second outcome, you get surprised.

Comment: Close, but it's not ambiguous at all. You _can_ supply a single array for varargs. I will clarify this for you in an edit of the answer.

Comment: @Gendarme http://stackoverflow.com/a/2925300/2761418

Comment: *"However, because `Integer` is an object, the compiler will use a single `Integer[]` as `Integer...`."* This seems rather arbitrary (perhaps ambiguous is the wrong word). The Java designers could have just as well decided to treat it as a `Integer[]...`, no?

Comment: They could have, but it would be somewhat self-defeating. It's convenient to pass a single array as a vararg. If you had a full-and-ready `Integer[]` you wanted to pass as `Integer...`, it would be much more complicated (and not very intuitive) to get each element and pass them as separate arguments. In contrast, if you had a single `Integer[]` you wanted to pass as an `Integer[]...`, you could either force it via the statement i showed or, if you didn't know about it, pass the argument as `new Integer[][] { myIntegerArray }`.

Comment: @Zircon In the signature `public static *<T>* List<T> asList(T... a)` I didn't get what the first `<T>` mean. I think `Arrays.*<Integer[]>*asList(new Integer[] {1, 2});` explains.

Comment: The `<T>` before the return type is declaring the generic `T`. This is used when a generic-typed method is used in a non-generic class. For example, if I make a method `public static <T extends Number> T doSomething(T...nums)`, I am forcing `T...` to be a vararg of any object that is `instanceof Number`, meaning `Number` and its child classes.

Comment: @Zircon Ok. I'm wrong. So, where does this `Arrays.<Integer[]>asList...` come from?

Comment: @Gustavo You were right, though. Making that call means you are declaring `<T>` to be `Integer[]`.