# How to tell Java the array I am supplying as a vararg not object or T?

Tags: java, variadic-functions

This is my code :

```
package ehsan;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] nums = new Random().doubles(120).toArray();
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(nums));
    }
}
```

And the result I get :

```
[[D@3d9750]
```

Apperantly `Arrays.asList` generates a `List` of `double[]` and not `double`. Consequently, How can I (possibly) specify `nums` I am supplying to `asList` is a vararg not a single `T`?

According to the question which is suggested as the original, what changes should I make to the code?

Comment: You can't - there's no such thing as a `List<double>`. I'm sure this is a dupe, but I may not have time to find it...

Comment: @JonSkeet, Come on mate, this differs from that...

Comment: I recently gave an answer that explains this behavior here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38397866/4793951 - There is no real shortcut to converting your `double[]` to `Double[]`, however...Maybe use streams to do it quickly?

Comment: @ehsan: I really don't think it does. Both questions are taking a `double[]` and trying to pass it into `Arrays.asList`, expressing surprise at the result type, basically. Where do you think the difference is? Which aspect of your question is not explained in the answers to that question?

Comment: @Zircon, thanks for the point, How can I conver `DoubleStream` to `Double[]`, is there `collect()` method available?

Comment: @JonSkeet, Sure, But I am confused, what should I change in my code to make it work?

Comment: This does both steps at once for you: `List<Double> numObjs = Arrays.stream(nums).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: @ehsan: "make it work" requires knowing what you're trying to achieve, which is hard to know here. Your existing code doesn't seem to try to be creating a `Double[]`...

Comment: @JonSkeet, all I am trying here is to convert `double[]` to `List` to print it simply :)

Comment: If you only need to print it, why not use `Arrays.toString(double[])`?

Comment: @Zircon, is there any difference between `Stream.of` and `Arrays.stream`?

Comment: `Stream.of` causes the same issue you faced here originally. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27888447/4793951

Comment: Thanks, Didn't know these delicate differences between `Stream.of` and `Arrays.stream` ....

Comment: @Zircon, just one another question, Is there any difference between `DoubleStream.of` and `Arrays.stream`?

Comment: @ehsan Since they both would return a `DoubleStream` in this case, it seems there isn't. I myself still prefer `Arrays.stream` because I find it more readable, though.