# Arbitrary Number of Arguments. Pass String[] as array

Tags: java, android

I'm having a simple issue, this is the method:

```
void someMethod(Object... args)
```

When i'm using `new String[]{"a", "b"}` as parameter, i see two params in method : `"a"`, `"b"` separately, however, when i'm using `null, new String[]{"a", "b"}`, param appearing as String array as expected.

Is there any way to transfer String array so it will be a String array in method using `Objects...` ?

Comment: by not using an array but some other structure (fx ArrayList)

Comment: @Selvin, i'm currently using ArrayList, but i think it's an overkill to use it only for few strings, do you think it's not?

Comment: @Selvin just compare : new String[]{"a", "b"} and ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>(); arrayList.add("a"); arrayList.add("b"), even in case of lines of code it's far more

Comment: *[If the last formal parameter is a variable arity parameter, the method is a variable arity method. Otherwise, it is a fixed arity method.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.1)*  ... T... is only a syntactic sugar for a T[] ... so it would not be possible

Comment: @Selvin, ok, thx, but just from your perpective, is it easier to user String[] with some dummy ignored object before it in the method itself, or call method from multiple places using ArrayList instead that would take a lot of lines unlike String[]

Comment: or `new Object[] { new String[]{"a", "b"} }`

Answer (score 0):

duplicate question from [Can I pass an array as arguments to a method with variable arguments in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925153/can-i-pass-an-array-as-arguments-to-a-method-with-variable-arguments-in-java)

Object... args is a syntactic sugar for a Object[].
when there is the null as first paramater and array as second he takes each as an object, but when there is an array of Strings he converts them to Objects.

Comment: Thx for the reply, but i actually want to stick to @Selvin suggestion : new Object[] { new String[]{"a", "b"} } because it fits my needs