# How to convert array into multiple variables in java

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, nashorn

**Not duplicate question**

As I stated downwards, I already checked how to work in java with different number of params. It wraps them into an array, and go ahead with it. But I need to pass **different number of params** to a function, **not an array**, since it will be treated with javascript

---

I am working with **Nashorn** in order to execute some javascript scripts in java.
I am trying to modularize as much as possible the code, in order to be easy to use.

I have the following function to call a javascript method already:

```
MyClass{
....
    public static Object call(ScriptObjectMirror ctx, String functionName, Object ...args ) {
        ScriptObjectMirror caller = ctxs.get(ctx); // assume this works, it brings correct data
        return caller.call(ctx, functionName, args);
    }
....
}
```

So, I have read different questions like [Can I pass an array as arguments to a method with variable arguments in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925153/can-i-pass-an-array-as-arguments-to-a-method-with-variable-arguments-in-java)

Where it states clearly that Object... is the same as Object[].

However, when I am working on javascript side, I receive different things depending on the args:

Lets say I do the following call:

```
MyClass.call(myCtx, "a", true, false);
```

It will call:

```
caller.call(myCtx, "a", [true, false]); //Javascript prints: [Ljava.lang.Object;@273d3dbb
```

But, If I do skip the method MyClass.call in order to directly invoke javascript function like this:

```
caller.call(myCtx, "a", true, false); //Javascript prints true, false
```

**THEREFOR**

I can understand that java internally works fine with both (Object... and Object[]) **BUT** since I am using Nashorn, I really need to be able to get args, and split them.

Something like:

```
public static Object call(ScriptObjectMirror ctx, String functionName, Object ...args ) {
    //Pseudocode of what I want to achieve
    for (arg: args) {
        arg1 = arg;
        arg2 = arg;
        argN = arg;
    }
    return caller.call(ctx, functionName, arg1, arg2, ..., argN);
```

}

Is there any way to achieve this? / Any workaround?

**NOTE**

I can not just in javascript side assume I always receive an array with different arguments, since it can be called from a lot of different places, and would mean to recode really a lot of code

Comment: Do you need to use vararg here ?

Comment: No you can't, except if you know the number of parameters in advance as you suggested.

Comment: @Krystian_K yes, I do, since it can receive any number of arguments

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Is it possible that a language like Java, does not support to make the exact same call from outside method to inner method? :O like: a(1,2,3) return b(1,2,3) for any ammount of params?

Comment: Well answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925153/can-i-pass-an-array-as-arguments-to-a-method-with-variable-arguments-in-java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I pass an array as arguments to a method with variable arguments in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925153/can-i-pass-an-array-as-arguments-to-a-method-with-variable-arguments-in-java)

Comment: It is a different question, as I linked that one already. In my case, I need to make a javascript call with different number of arguments. That question only answers that you can work with that in java, but does not really give a workaround to call a method with all the params, instead of wrap them into arrays

Answer (score 1):

You can't do exactly what Java could do, but you can do something similar.

Javascript function does support receive unlimited numbers of parameters. You can access the parameters by `arguments` keyword.

Please kindly read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments).

**For example:**

```js
function foo(){
    for(var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++){
       document.write(arguments[i] +'<br />');
    }
}

foo("A", "B", "C", 1, 2, 3);
```

Comment: Thats a decent workaround, not exactly what I would like to achieve, but it can help if I do not find anything better. Thanks!