# Apache Spark Row of multiple String fields to single Row with String array converting Exception

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I try to implement such code:

```
    StructType dataStruct = new StructType()
            .add("items", DataTypes.createArrayType(DataTypes.StringType, false), false);
    ExpressionEncoder<Row> encoder = RowEncoder.apply(dataStruct);

    Dataset<Row> arrayItems = transactions.map((MapFunction<Row, Row>) row -> {
        List<String> items = new LinkedList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
            if (row.getString(i) != null)
                items.add(row.getString(i));
        }
        System.out.println(items);
        return RowFactory.create(items.toArray());
    }, encoder);
```

to convert dataset with such schema:

```
|user<String>|item1<String>|item2<String>|item3<String>|...|item12<String>|
```

to dataset with such schema:

```
|item<String[]>|
```

but i take following exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.String is not a valid external type for schema of array

I don't understand why RowFactory takes as argument String, not String[]? Can somebody help me, what I should do in this situation?

Data example:

```
user|item1|item2|item3|item4|item5|item6|item7|item8|item9|item10|item11|item12
Bob|01W|01J|01W|01J|01W|01J|01W|01J|01W|01J|null|null
John|03T|018T|003H|A44I|03T|null|003H|A44I|03T|018T|003H|null
Bill|CMZI|UDAG|01W|null|null|01J|018T|003H|A44I|018T|003H|A44I
```

Comment: please share data, otherwise your code is not going to be reproducible.

Comment: Which version of Spark do you use and on which line exception is?

Comment: I use Spark 2.2.1. Exception is on line "return RowFactory.create(items.toArray());"

Comment: @mtoto It is reproducible as is. It is just a tricky one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because varargs in Java are just syntactic sugar and

```
Object ... values
```

is equivalent to

```
Object[] values
```

so

```
return RowFactory.create(items.toArray());
```

will expand the array. You'll need a nested structure:

```
Object[] rowItems =  {items.toArray()};
RowFactory.create(rowItems));
```

Further reading [Can I pass an array as arguments to a method with variable arguments in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2925153/8371915)

Comment: @JackLoki I am glad I could help. This is a nice question. Would you consider [upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)? :)