# JUnit MethodSource with single array varargs problems

Tags: arrays, junit, arguments, variadic-functions

I have a problem with single/multiple arrays as `varargs` parameters used in `JUnit5` `MethodSource`'s `Arguments`.

If multiple arrays (empty or not) are passed, everything's fine, but if only a single array is passed, the `Arguments.of()` varargsunwraps the array and the originally intended as-array source is destroyed, which is not what I want. The problem relates to any `varargs` method parameters, not just to `Arguments`.

Method Arguments source:

```java
static Object[] objectsWithNull = new Object[] { null }; // -> [null] intended array test argument

public static final List<Arguments> objSource() {
    return List.of(
            Arguments.of(objectsWithNull) // varargsArguments.of(Object...) unwraps array, not desired -> null
    );
}

public static final List<Arguments> objSources() {
    return List.of(
            Arguments.of(objectsWithNull, objectsWithNull) // -> [null], [null] OK
    );
}
```

Test method utilizing `MethodSource` arguments in 'TestClasses':

```java
@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("objSource")
public <T> void myTest(final T t2) {
    assertDoesNotThrow(() -> { // test code
    });
}

@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("objSources")
public <T> void myTest(final T t1, final T t2) {
    assertDoesNotThrow(() -> { // test code
    });
}
```

Actually desired: -> [null] as in `objSources`

```java
Arguments.of(objectsWithNull,objectsWithNull); // -> [null], [null] OK
```

Even worse, while for multiple empty arrays there's no problem:

```java
Object[] objectsEmpty = new Object[0]; 
Arguments.of(objectsEmpty,objectsEmpty); // -> [], [] OK
```

A single empty array will throw
*org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ParameterResolutionException: No ParameterResolver registered for parameter [T arg0] in method ... [public  void ... TestClasses.myTest(T,T)]*:

```java
Arguments.of(objectsEmpty); // -> throws
```

Even more confusing, while using a typed null Object reference works, using a plain null value or a typed null array reference will throw an Exception:

```java
static Object nullObjRef = (Object) null;
static Object[] nullArrayRef = (Object[]) null;

public static final List<Arguments> objSource() {
    return List.of(
            Arguments.of(nullObjRef), // #A -> OK
            Arguments.of(nullArrayRef), // #B -> throws org.junit.platform.commons.PreconditionViolationException: argument array must not be null
            Arguments.of(null) // #C -> throws org.junit.platform.commons.PreconditionViolationException: argument array must not be null
    );
}
```

While passing a null array reference causing an internal `NPE` in #B might be understandable, #A vs. #C (typed `null` reference vs. plain `null`) is not quite.

Also, a single empty array throwing a `ParameterResolutionException` seems rather random to me (while probably just a caught internal `NPE` or `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`), instead of just passing through the empty array.

Finally, I'd like to know, if there's an easy, clean way of avoiding the unwrapping effect of single array arguments by `varargs`, as described in the first example, without the inconvenience of double-wrapping and unwrapping single or multiple arrays from inside a container object, which is passed to `Arguments.of()`.

EDIT:
When testing this, I've also found, that passing an array into a `varargs` parameter, the result is an array-wrapped array. Didn't cross such issues before trying to pass on arrays as test values per `JUnit` `Arguments` and `MethodSource`, though. Maybe reading this first would've helped:
[Passing arrays with varargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925153/can-i-pass-an-array-as-arguments-to-a-method-with-variable-arguments-in-java)

Anyway, these effects make using `Arguments` in conjunction with arrays more difficult.

Answer (score 1):

To be clear, `JUnit` doesn't unwrap the array. JUnit uses reflection to call test cases with or without method parameters. This is the ambiguous part.

`java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke` signature is:

```java
public Object invoke(Object obj, Object... args) {
// ...
}
```

When a method called via reflection the parameters passed as an Object array.
JUnit supports multiple signature to provide parameters to test cases. Because of this, it is hard to decide what is the best. JUnit passes parameters as it got by the provider.

#### Workaround

Honestly I don't this this is the bulletproof solution, but it works.
Sine 5.8 JUnit supports named payloads to provide arguments to test case. This factory method wraps the arguments. `Named` provider is designed for naming parameterized test executions. This is why I'm saying the following code is just a working workaround.

```java
static List<Arguments> objSource() {
    return List.of(Arguments.arguments(
            Named.named("Null array", objectsWithNull))
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'll test it out.