# Why is the type of the var-arg argument "over approximated"?

Tags: java, types, variadic-functions

If I understand it correctly, `Integer[]` is a subtype of `Object[]`. You can for instance do

```
Object[] objs = new Integer[] { 1, 2, 3 };
```

While playing around with var-args I realized, that it seems like the compiler "over approixmates" the array type for no obvious reason.

The program below for instance, prints `123` `123`. Wouldn't it make sense / be more precise if it printed `123` `6`?

```
class Test {

    public static Object combine(Object... objs) {

        if (objs instanceof Integer[]) {

            int sum = 0;
            for (Integer i : (Integer[]) objs)
                sum += i;
            return sum;

        } else {

            String concat = "";
            for (Object o : objs)
                concat += o;
            return concat;

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(combine("1", "2", "3"));  // prints 123
        System.out.println(combine(1, 2, 3));        // prints 123
    }
}
```

I guess my question could be summed up as: Would any contradiction / problem arise if the JLS was defined to pass `T[]` as argument, where `T` was the least upper bound of the types of all arguments given?

---

**Edit:** I realize that I, in this particular case, could overload the the `combine` method to take `Integer[]` as well ([ideone demo](http://ideone.com/xIcIC)). Still, the question remains of why this design was chosen.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: overloaded method resolution and varargs -- confusing example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032901/java-overloaded-method-resolution-and-varargs-confusing-example)

Comment: I've seen that question (and upvoted it!) That question concerns overloading though, which is a completely different issue as I see it?

Comment: Agreed, it's a different issue. This question is about the compiler's packaging of the varargs array, not about method resolution.

Comment: Sorry, My fault. I don't unknow how to undo the closed vote.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As to this specific question:

> Would any contradiction / problem arise if the JLS was defined to pass T[] as argument, where T was the least upper bound of the types of all arguments given?

Yes, because the array is not read-only; it's writable:

```
package com.example.test;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Varargs3 {
    public static Object[] changeLastArgument(Object... objs) {
        if (objs.length > 0)
            objs[objs.length-1] = "Pow!";
        return objs;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(
            Arrays.toString(changeLastArgument(1,2,3))
        );
    }
}
```

which prints

```
[1, 2, Pow!]
```

If the JLS was defined the way you are asking (e.g. for `foo(T... args)`, if you call `foo(a,b,c)` then the compiler constructs an array of the least upper bound of the types a,b,c), then this case would allow a runtime error: the invocation of `changeLastArgument(1,2,3)` would create an array of type `Integer[]`, but the `changeLastArgument()` method would attempt to assign `"Pow!"` to the last element and you'd get a runtime error.

The declaration of `changeLastArgument()` is specifying its input types, and therefore it should be able to assume its input argument is truly an `Object[]` and not a subtype of `Object[]`, so that it can safely modify the input arguments. (This is similar to the [PECS principle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs) -- in order for a `List<T>` to be both safely readable and writable, you can't use any wildcards like `List<? extends T>` -- which is safely readable but not safely writable -- or `List<? super T>` -- which is safely writable but not safely readable.)

Comment: Hah! I think you nailed it! Passing a `new Integer[] {1, 2, 3}` results in an `ArrayStoreException` as you point out. You deserve a  Nice answer badge for this IMO :-)

Comment: @aioobe this is not a killer argument. you can pass one yourself: `Arrays.toString(changeLastArgument(new Integer[]{1,2,3}))` and get ArrayStoreException.

Comment: Sure, but then it's at least "my fault". It would be *far worse* if this was the default behavior when simply doing `combine(1, 2, 3)`.

Answer (score 3):

To print `6` as an result, the compiler would have to be clever enough to realize, that all arguments can be boxed into a similar wrapper class.

I guess, this is just too much effort or too difficult to specify correctly for some very rare cases.

---

Besides the question, well, it looks like, the simple rule is: the array is *always* of type `Object[]` (if the varargs type is `Object`), here's some demonstration code:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    temp("1", "2", "3");
    temp(1,2,3);
    temp(String.class, Integer.class);
}

public static void temp(Object... objs) {
    System.out.println(objs.getClass());
}
```

Output:

```
class [Ljava.lang.Object;
class [Ljava.lang.Object;
class [Ljava.lang.Object;
```

Comment: Aha, that's a good theory, +1. An identical specification already exists though for overloaded methods, where "the most precise" method gets called.

Comment: Regarding your edit: Yes, I know. The parameter type defines how the argument gets compiled. My question is, since `Integer[]` is a subtype of `Object[]` why doesn't the compiler compile the argument type to the most specific type, i.e., `Integer[]` instead of `Object[]`?

Comment: But why should it be the most precise in this case? There's no requirement; it needs to match a method, and once it does that, there's no requirement to try to be clever and allocate Integer[] instead of Object[].

Comment: I thought the example in my question provided an example of why I might benefit from getting the most precise type.

Comment: @aioobe (the `throws` was an ideone artifact ;) )

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like `combine(1, 2, 3)` will yield a `int[]` rather than `Integer[]`. Since an `int[]` array is not an instance of an `Integer[]` array, the first check fails, and you fall back to the concat block.

Comment: Uhm, no, since `int[]` is not a subtype of `Object[]`. You can't do `Object[] o = new int[] {1, 2, 3 };`. Put another way, there's no way to pass an `int[]` to a method accepting an `Object[]`.

Answer (score 1):

The JLS specifies this behavior (creation of an array of elements of the type that is the variable arity parameter type, i.e. if the vararg method is `foo(Bar bar, Baz baz, T...)` then the array created on method invocation is of type `T[]`), if you find the right spot:

From [JLS 8.4.1](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.4.1) (Oracle site having trouble at the moment, I had to use the Internet Archive):

> If the last formal parameter is a
>   variable arity parameter of type T, it
>   is considered to define a formal
>   parameter of type T[]. The method is
>   then a variable arity method.
>   Otherwise, it is a fixed arity method.
>   Invocations of a variable arity method
>   may contain more actual argument
>   expressions than formal parameters.
>   All the actual argument expressions
>   that do not correspond to the formal
>   parameters preceding the variable
>   arity parameter will be evaluated and
>   the results stored into an array that
>   will be passed to the method
>   invocation (§15.12.4.2).

From JLS 15.12.4.2:

> 15.12.4.2 Evaluate Arguments The process of evaluating of the argument
>   list differs, depending on whether the
>   method being invoked is a fixed arity
>   method or a variable arity method
>   (§8.4.1).
>
> If the method being invoked is a
>   variable arity method (§8.4.1) m, it
>   necessarily has n>0 formal parameters.
>   The final formal parameter of m
>   necessarily has type T[] for some T,
>   and m is necessarily being invoked
>   with k >= 0 actual argument expressions.
>
> If m is being invoked with k != n actual
>   argument expressions, or, if m is
>   being invoked with k=n actual argument
>   expressions and the type of the kth
>   argument expression is not assignment
>   compatible with T[], then the argument
>   list (e1, ... , en-1, en, ...ek) is
>   evaluated as if it were written as
>   (e1, ..., en-1, new T[]{en, ..., ek}).
>
> The argument expressions (possibly
>   rewritten as described above) are now
>   evaluated to yield argument values.
>   Each argument value corresponds to
>   exactly one of the method's n formal
>   parameters.
>
> The argument expressions, if any, are
>   evaluated in order, from left to
>   right. If the evaluation of any
>   argument expression completes
>   abruptly, then no part of any argument
>   expression to its right appears to
>   have been evaluated, and the method
>   invocation completes abruptly for the
>   same reason.The result of evaluating
>   the jth argument expression is the jth
>   argument value, for 1 <= j <= n. Evaluation
>   then continues, using the argument
>   values, as described below.

So I maintain my original answer (see below).

---

I believe the answer is in the declaration:

```
public static Object combine(Object... objs)
```

The compiler matches this method, and therefore for varargs it allocates an `Object[]`. There is no reason for it to allocate an `Integer[]`.

---

trial test:

```
package com.example.test;
public class Varargs1 {
    public static void varargs(Object... objs) {
        System.out.println(objs.getClass());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        varargs("1", "2", "3");
        varargs(1, 2, 3);

        Integer[] ints = {1,2,3};
        varargs(ints); // Eclipse yields the following warning:
        /* 
         * The argument of type Integer[] should explicitly be 
         * cast to Object[] for the invocation of the varargs 
         * method varargs(Object...) from type Varargs1. 
         * It could alternatively be cast to Object for a 
         * varargs invocation
         */
    }
}
```

which prints:

```
class [Ljava.lang.Object;
class [Ljava.lang.Object;
class [Ljava.lang.Integer;
```

---

Finally, if you *want* the compiler to be more specific, use generic methods:

```
package com.example.test;

public class Varargs2 {
    public static <T> void varargs(T... objs) {
        System.out.println(objs.getClass());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        varargs("1", "2", "3");
        varargs(1, 2, 3);
        varargs(1, "2", 3); // warning from Eclipse:
        /*
         * Type safety : A generic array of 
         * Object&Comparable<?>&Serializable
         * is created for a varargs parameter
         */
    }
}
```

which prints:

```
class [Ljava.lang.String;
class [Ljava.lang.Integer;
class [Ljava.lang.Comparable;
```

Comment: Yes, I know. I did the `getClass` check myself. My question is *why* doesn't the compiler / JLS allocate an `Integer[]` instead? It would be more precise, no?

Comment: The JLS says exactly what the JLS says, regardless of whether something else would be better. Although there's probably a symmetry here: from the method resolution side of varargs, it finds the most specific method; from the consumer (calling) side of varargs, it finds the *least* specific type (which is the type of the declaring method's variable arity parameter)

Comment: My question is not about how it works, or what the JLS says. My question is, as stated from the beginning, *Would any contradiction / problem arise if the JLS was defined to pass T[] as argument, where T was the least upper bound of the types of all arguments given?*

Comment: Ah... ok, somehow I missed that part.

Comment: Added a new answer which answers that question.

Answer (score 0):

Well you are not sending a Integer[] into combine function. That's why it's not working as you expect.

Use

```
System.out.println(combine(new Integer[] {1, 2, 3}));
```

to make it work.

Comment: Ah, good point. However, why don't the compiler / JLS do exactly this for me if I provide it with the arguments `1, 2, 3` ?

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that you haven't specified a type that the varargs should incur.

The following shows what I mean:

```
/**
 * @author The Elite Gentleman.
 *
 */
public class Test {

    public static Object combine(Object... objs) {
        System.out.println("combine()");
        System.out.println(objs.getClass().getName());

        if (objs instanceof Integer[]) {

            int sum = 0;
            for (Integer i : (Integer[]) objs)
            sum += i;
            return sum;

        } else {

            String concat = "";
            for (Object o : objs) {
            System.out.println(o.getClass().getName());
            concat += o;
            }
            return concat;

        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("1");
        System.out.println(combine(new String[] {"1", "2", "3"}));
        System.out.println(combine(new Integer[] {1, 2, 3}));

        System.out.println("2");
        System.out.println(combine("1", "2", "3"));
        System.out.println(combine(1, 2, 3));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1
combine()
[Ljava.lang.String;
java.lang.String
java.lang.String
java.lang.String
123
combine()
[Ljava.lang.Integer;
6
2
combine()
[Ljava.lang.Object;
java.lang.String
java.lang.String
java.lang.String
123
combine()
[Ljava.lang.Object;
java.lang.Integer
java.lang.Integer
java.lang.Integer
123
```

It's clear that by not passing an "untyped" array, the JVM converts it to an `Object[]` that is passed to the `combine()` method.

*PS, I couldn't find the JLS as the Oracle Server is down.*

Comment: I don't understand your sentence about "generics". Care to elaborate?

Comment: Right. Still, that wasn't my question :P My question was why JLS is designed to "over approximate" the type, and why it's not defined to go for the most precise type.

Comment: I guess I over-read the question....lol...I need to carefully read the JLS to understand (*cough* Oracle) when the server comes back up